# How secure are IP restrictions on Azure functions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-security

I'm setting up an Azure function that should only be accessible from two networks. I've configured the function with ip restrictions limiting access to the two outgoing IPs of those networks. What I'm wondering is how secure is this solution ? How difficult would it be for potential intruders to fake their origin IP to get around this ? In addition to IP restrictions the function app uses Azure AD to authenticate clients.

Answer (score 1):

Access restrictions allow you to control who can access your app over the network. How access is granted is controlled by prioritized allow/deny lists. Azure Virtual Network IP addresses or subnets can be used here. Denying all entries is implied when there are multiple entries found.

A feature of Azure App Service allows access restrictions to be applied to workloads. Deployment options include web apps, APIs, Linux apps, Linux container apps, and functions.

The FROM address of your application's request is compared to the access restriction list every time it receives a request. Whenever the FROM address is within a subnet containing service endpoints of Microsoft.Web, it is compared with your virtual network rules in your access restriction list. Using the list of rules, an HTTP 403 error is returned if the address doesn't allow access.

In my opinion, the IP restrictions on Azure functions provide enough security..

Comment: Considering that DDoS Basic is automatically enabled for free, I agree with @ben stokes here. That said, IP spoofing is not the only risk and you might consider looking for a private connectivity pattern or a WAF protecting your endpoint (in front of AppGW/APIM for instance) if you want to maximize security. It is of course all about your business need and the level of confidentiality for the data in transit here.